# Can't get ZSH working on CentOS

Tags: centos, zsh

I've been using zsh for a couple of years now on Ubuntu and really like it a lot.

I've installed it on our production server as well, which is running CentOS 5.2, and it works just fine.

However, I just installed it via yum on a new VM I created to use as a development box, to replicate our production box as closely as possible.

Although yum shows that it is definitely installed (/bin/zsh) and that it is set as my shell, it does not appear to be working. Instead of creating the .zshrc and .profile files in my home directory, it created a .tcshrc file. Also, I did not receive the default configuration menu that is always displayed once you begin using ZSH, and none of the features (like advanced tab comple

Comment: What do `echo $version` and `echo $ZSH_VERSION` tell you?

Comment: What happens when you type `/bin/zsh` on the command line?  Choosing your shell isn't the same as installing it.

Comment: Sorry guys.. I got busy with work projects and neglected this thread. Thank you for your responses.

@dennis-williamson  `echo $version` produces a blank line. `echo $ZSH_VERSION` tells me "4.2.6"



@Redmumba Thanks, but I did ensure that I installed zsh before choosing it as my shell. Typing `/bin/zsh` starts zsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing a shell on a system will not go back adn add dot-rc files to your current home directory. You can copy the defaults from /etc/skel/.zshrc or make your own. ZSH will prompt you to create a customized one on first run if none exists. If a .tcshrc file got created, I think it would only be because you ran that shell.You can see what shell you are running by executing `echo $SHELL`. You can change the default shell for a user to any shell installed on the system and approved in /etc/shells by executing `passwd -s`.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the defaults in `/etc/skel/.zshrc`. That fixed my problem. You sure about `passwd -s` though? I just checked the man page for `passwd` and it doesn't appear to have an `-s` switch.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. You must be using a `passwd` from a different package. Here is from my man page: "-s     This  option  is  used to change the user login shell. A normal user may only change the login shell for their own account, the super user may change the login shell for any account."